# Сложить два вещественных числа

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Написал скрипт, складывающий 2 числа

```
read -p 'x = ' x
read -p 'y = ' y
s=$(($x+$y))
echo Sum is $s
```

Но оказалось, что он работает только для целых, а для вещественных выдаёт ошибку

> syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator

Как исправить, чтобы для вещественных чисел тоже работало?

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash не поддерживает операции с плавающей точкой. нужно использовать внешнюю утилиту, например, bc.

```
x=0.01
y=0.001 
z=$(echo "$x + $y" | bc)

echo Sum is $z
```

Comment: Что ж он так? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy, каждому свое. Нужна плавучка? Пишите скрипты на питоне

Comment: @Qwertiy можно также на питоне, на awk, на perl и ruby.